# Origin and significance of E-I-E-I-O in the Old MacDonald song

Tags: meaning, song-lyrics, historical-context, wording-choice, nursery-rhyme

The well-known children's song "Old MacDonald had a Farm" has lyrics in the following format:

> Old MacDonald had a farm
> E-I-E-I-O !
> And on that farm he had {article} {singular or plural creatures}
> E-I-E-I-O !
> With a {creature-appropriate sound} {creature-appropriate sound} here
> And a {creature-appropriate sound} {creature-appropriate sound} there
> Here a {creature-appropriate sound}, there a  {creature-appropriate sound}
> Everywhere a {creature-appropriate sound} {creature-appropriate sound}
> Old MacDonald had a farm
> E-I-E-I-O !

where:

- {article} is "a" or "some"
- {singular or plural creatures} is any farmyard animal or bird, such as dog, duck, hen, cat, cow, etc.
- {creature-appropriate sound} is the sound associated with the farmyard animal in question, such as woof, quack, cluck, meow, moo, etc. respectively

So the song would go something like the following:

> Old MacDonald had a farm
> E-I-E-I-O !
> And on that farm he had some ducks
> E-I-E-I-O !
> With a quack quack here
> And a quack quack there
> Here a quack, there a quack
> Everywhere a quack quack
> Old MacDonald had a farm
> E-I-E-I-O !
> *continue with new creature*

While most of the lyrics are self-explanatory, I'm wondering about the vowel sequence *E-I-E-I-O !* What is the origin and significance of this particular sequence? Why not, say, *A-E-I-O-U !* instead? Is there a historical, linguistic, or semantic explanation of why the song ended up with *E-I-E-I-O !* as the climax of the refrain?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As with any folk song, the origins of the lyrics can be a bit murky, but given transcriptions collected by folklorists in the early part of the twentieth century of this or related songs, we see that the E-I-E-I-O isn't meant to refer to the letters but is rather just a vocalization to continue the melody. An Ozarks version from 1922 has [lyrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_MacDonald_Had_a_Farm):

> Old Missouri had a mule, he-hi-he-hi-ho,
>  And on this mule there
> were two ears, he-hi-he-hi-ho.
>  With a flip-flop here and a
> flip-flop there,
>  And here a flop and there a flop and everywhere
> a flip-flop
>  Old Missouri had a mule, he-hi-he-hi-ho.

In a [related song from England](https://www.vwml.org/record/PG/5/155), there is a shorter bit of vocalization which the transcriber notated as “ī ō” (note the macron to indicate a long sound). So the answer to why not “AEIOU” is that those aren’t actually letter names being sung but simply an abstract vocalization.

Comment: See also https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/211716/non-verbal-lyrics-in-songs-is-there-a-nice-name-for-these