# What's the role of "a, a" at the end of every stanza in Jaufré Rudel "No sap chantar qui so non di"?

Tags: poetry, meter

At page 165 of the book *Los trovadores. Historia literaria y textos* by [Martín de Riquer](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mart%C3%AD_de_Riquer_i_Morera) one finds the text of the *cansó* *No sap chantar qui so non di* (262, 3) by the troubadour [Jaufré Rudel](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaufre_Rudel):

> No sap chantar qui so non di,
> ni vers trobar qui motz no fa,
> ni conois de rima co·s va
> si razo non enten en si.
> Mas lo mieus chans comens'aissi,
> com pluz l'auziretz, mais valra, a, a.
>
> Nuils hom no·s meravill de mi
> s'ieu am so que ja no·m veira,
> que·l cor joi d'autr'amor non ha
> mas de cela qu'ieu anc no vi,
> ni per nuill joi aitan no ri,
> e no sai quals bes m'en venra, a, a.
>
> Colps de joi me fer, que m'ausi,
> et ponha d'amor que·m sostra
> la carn don lo cors magrira;
> et anc mais tan greu no·m feri,
> ni per nuill colp tan no langui,
> quar no cove ni no s'esca, a, a.
>
> Anc tan suau no m'adurmi
> mos esperitz tost no fos la,
> ni tan d'ira non ac de sa
> mos cors ades no fos aqui;
> e quan mi resveill al mati
> totz mos bos sabers mi desva, a, a.
>
> Ben sai c'anc de lei no·m jauzi,
> ni ja de mi no·s jauzira,
> ni per son amic no·m tenra
> ni coven no·m fara de si;
> anc no·m dis ver ni no·m menti
> e no sai si ja s'o fara, a, a.
>
> Bos es lo vers, qu'anc no·i falhi,
> e tot so que·i es ben esta;
> e sel que de mi l'apenra
> gart se no·l franha ni·l pessi;
> car si l'auran en Caersi
> en Bertrans e·l coms en Tolza, a, a.
>
> Bos es lo vers, e faran hi
> calque re don hom chantara, a, a.

My question is about these "a, a" which appear at the end of every *cobla*. According to the book, all verses are octosyllables, so this "a, a" must be part of the last syllable in the last verse of the stanza. But why has the troubadour put these "a, a" at the end of each stanza? This is even maintained in the Spanish translation given in the book. For instance, the translation of the *tornada* is

> Bueno es el verso, y de él harán algo con lo que se cantará, a, a.

Is some kind of indication for the jongleur who will sing the *cansó*, perhaps that the last syllable of the stanza should be longer?

In fact, in Riquer's book there is a footnote which says

> *a, a*. Hay que ver aquí un fenómeno musical parecido a lo que ocurría en el canto litúrgico
> (principalmente en las secuencias) cuando se repetía el neuma sólo de la vocal final de un grupo de versos a manera de refranh, o estribillo (cfr. H. Anglès, *La música a Catalunya fins al segle XIII*, pág. 233 ).

But I found this quite difficult to understand. My   attempt of translation is:

> *a, a*. One must see here a musical phenomenon similar to what occurred in liturgical chant (mainly in sequences) when the neume of only the final vowel of a group of verses was repeated as a *refranh* or refrain (cf. H. Anglès, *La música a Catalunya fins al segle XIII*, page 233).

Comment: @Randal'Thor: Maybe we could have a tag for minor Romance languages — Catalan, Asturian, Occitan, Provençal, Galician, Romansh, and so forth.

Comment: I know nothing of Occitan, but it looks to me like one of those groups of nonsense syllables that were often added to lines of songs - 'fa la la', 'oh oh' and the like.

Comment: @KateBunting: not only "were often" but still are often added to lines of songs. *Goodbye Yellow Brick Road* (1973) by John Elton comes immediately to mind (*Beyond the yellow brick road, ah, ah*), but there are undoubtedly many even more recent examples.

Comment: @KateBunting: These cannot be extra syllables: according to the book, all verses are octosyllables.

Comment: @PeterShor: I'm not completely sure that the comparison with these recent examples is really relevant for a composition from the first half of the 12th century.

Comment: @Charo: Why can't they be sung as extra syllables? Why would repeating the a that ends the last word in a stanza while singing count as an extra syllable?  Do you know the exact rules that *los trovadores* used for counting syllables? Are they written down somewhere?

Comment: @PeterShor: Yes, the rules are the same that the ones we use in Catalan meter.

Comment: So the rules have been exactly the same for the last nine centuries? The rules for counting syllables in iambic pentameter have changed in English (although not by very much).

Comment: @PeterShor: From Riquer's book, page 35: "Por lo que se refiere a la medida del verso, hay que tener presente que el cómputo de las sílabas se hace de acuerdo con el número de la última tónica, en oposición al uso italiano y castellano, que cuenta una sílaba más tras la última acentuada". That is, "As for the measurement of the verse, it's important to keep in mind that syllable counting is done based on the number of the last stressed syllable, in contrast to the Italian and Spanish usage, which counts one more syllable after the last stressed one."

Comment: @Charo: From that description, if the first *a* at the end of *valra* was stressed, and the next two *a*'s were unstressed, wouldn't you get the right number of syllables?

Comment: @PeterShor: For instance: "e / no / sai / quals / bes / m'en / ven/ra". The word "venra" is a verb in future tense, so the stressed syllable is the last one. This is something that at least Occitan, Catalan, Castilian and Italian have in common. I agree with what you have said in your last comment: this means that "a, a" are not extra syllables.

Comment: So the easiest answer to this question is probably to take the text as written, with the extra *a a* as two unstressed syllables at the end of each stanza.

Comment: Related: [Origin and significance of E-I-E-I-O](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/17867/289)